# SKNode not updating when text changes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, sknode

I have an SKNode which contains 2 sub nodes (a sprite node w/an image and an SKLabelNode above the image which prints the number of available units).

Previously, after each time the USER 'spent' a unit the counters would update by removing the previous unit and adding a new one.

That was working, but obviously quite inefficient. Now I'm trying to grab the existing node and update its text like so...

```
        let newNode = createUnitCounter(type: type, nation: nation, count: countStr)
        if let existingNode = iterator.filter({ $0.name == newNode.name }).first?.children.filter({ $0 is SKLabelNode }).first as? SKLabelNode {
            existingNode.text = countStr
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.addChild(newNode)
            }
        }
```

Using breakpoints I can see that the node should be updating (it's text shows the proper values when I type `po existingNode.text` in the console), but the screen never shows the update. Other nodes I've refactored are updating on the screen, but not this one.

**How do tell the node to redraw (e.g. something like `existingNode.setNeedsDisplay()`)?**

Here's how I create the node originally in `createUnitCounter:type:nation:count` ...

```
func createUnitCounter(type: UnitType, nation: Nation, count: String) -> SKNode {
    let node = SKNode()
    node.name = type.prefix + ElId.Nodes.counter

    let image = createCounterImage(mode: .offense, type: type, nation: nation)
    assignCounterPosition(to: image, of: type)
    node.addChild(image)
    
    let label = createCounterLabel(text: count, position: nil, type: type)
    label.verticalAlignmentMode = .bottom
    assignCounterPosition(to: label, of: type)
    node.addChild(label)
    
    return node
}

func createCounterLabel(text: String, position: CGPoint?, type: UnitType?) -> SKLabelNode {
    let node = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: Assets.font)
    node.text = text
    node.zPosition = Position.zUIElementH

    if type == selectedUnitType { node.fontColor = Colors.red }
    
    if let p = position { node.position = p }
    
    return node
}

func createCounterImage(mode: GameMode, type: UnitType = .infantry, nation: Nation = .usa) -> SKSpriteNode {
...
}
```

Comment: DispatchQueue -- so you're in a background thread here? can you say why? that might be your problem. ie try wrapping the text update just like you do the addchild cmd

Comment: The addChild works; the problem is in the other block of the condition (when the child node already exists instead of the else). I tried wrapping "existingNode.text = countStr" but that didn't work :(

Comment: Actually the problem seems to be the iterator. I recently switched all of my for loops to iterators and wrapped all the tree modifications in DQ.main calls to ensure they were serial because I was getting a mutated collection error somewhere. That fixed the previous bug, but it appears that when I copy the iterator it breaks the reference for the individual nodes (although when check identity '===' still says it's true...)

Answer (score 0):

So I isolated the issue to the fact that it was chaining the filters through an iterator which broke the node's reference. When I switched the iterator back out to the children array, everything was working. However that was going to create issues, so I found a similar method and for some reason I was able to keep the iterator and the references survived when accessing the same node independent of the iterator and then accessing that...

```
        let newNode = createUnitCounter(type: type, nation: nation, count: countStr)
        if let existingNode = children.makeIterator().filter({ $0.name == newNode.name }).first {
            for child in existingNode.children {
                if let label = child as? SKLabelNode { label.text = countStr }
            }
        } else {
            addChild(newNode)
        }
```